# C# asmx web service randomly started redirecting

Tags: c#, web-services

Monday afternoon I was working on a web service, was able to request the .asmx file in the browser and was given the menu of usable methods and was able to invoke them from the browser with no problems. Tuesday comes around and each time I access it, I get an "Object moved to here" message that links to a nonexistent login.aspx page.

Here's the .asmx.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace LegacyReports
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Summary description for Example
  /// </summary>
  [WebService(Namespace = "http://company.com/")]
  [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
  [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)] 
  //[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
  public class Example : System.Web.Services.WebService
  {

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false)]
    public List<ExampleData> ExampleDataSet()
    {
      Context.Database db = new Context.Database();
      String sql = @"SELECT TOP 10 * FROM sometable";
      SqlDataReader reader = db.ExecuteReader(sql);
      List<ExampleData> data = new List<ExampleData>();

      while (reader.Read())
      {
        int a = Convert.ToInt32(reader["somecolumn"]);
        String b = (String)reader["anothercolumn"] + " " + (String)reader["someotherrandomcolumn"];
        data.Add(new ExampleData() { a = a, b = b });
      }

      return data;
    }
  }

  public class ExampleData
  {
    public int a { get; set; }
    public String b { get; set; }
  }
}
```

I'm just not sure why it would work one day then stop the next day. Could it be something with IIS?

Comment: Something has changed, if the code hasn't then it will be the environment it is contained

Comment: I'm wondering if something's up with my IIS. I reverted the code environment back to when I knew it was working and I'm still getting the issue. I'm just wondering what would suddenly require everything to go to a login.aspx file that doesn't exist in the environment.

Comment: Have you checked your web.config file to make sure that it allows anonymous users to access the web service? If forms authentication is enabled, there is no exclusion for the asmx, and the user has not logged in previously, it's normal for a redirect to the login page to occur.

Comment: Forms authentication is enabled. Does that use the "membership providers" to validate users? I'm wondering if any changes to the provider could be affecting this, if so.